# Enviar arraylist desde formulario jsp a servlet y mostrar resultados en otro jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, web

Estoy empezando a conocer el desarrollo java web y estoy desarrollando un ejercicio el cual debo llenar un `array` desde un formulario `jsp`, enviarlo a un `servlet` para llenar con los datos del formulario el `array` y mostrar los resultados en una tabla de otro `jsp`,

Ejemplo:

En `index.jsp` tengo el `form`, lo envío a `ListarPrendas.java` y lo muestro en `ListadoDePrendas.jsp`, sin embargo intenté usar `RequestDispatcher` `forward` para procesar el `array` en el `servlet` y solo pedir datos en el `listado.jsp`, pero no pasa nada, aquí les dejo el código de las 3 paginas:

#### index.jsp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="index.jsp">Inicio</a> <a href="ListadoDePrendas.jsp">Listar Prendas</a>
        <form action="ListarPrendas" method="POST">  
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Codigo:</td><td><input type="text" name="codigo" required="Falta campo!"></td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Nombre:</td><td><input type="text" name="nombre" required="Falta campo!"></td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Marca:</td><td><input type="text" name="marca" required="Falta campo!"></td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Talla:</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="talla">
                        <option value="S">Small</option>
                        <option value="M">Medium</option>
                        <option value="L">Large</option>                        
                        </select>
                     </td>
                </tr>   
                <tr>
                    <td>Stock:</td><td><input type="text" name="stock" required="Falta campo!"></td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Temporada:</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="temporada">
                        <option value="true">SI</option>
                        <option value="false">NO</option>                                              
                        </select>
                     </td>
                </tr>     
                <tr>
                    <td><button type="submit">Agregar</button></td><td><button type="reset">Limpiar</button></td>
                </tr>
            </table>                
         </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### servlet ListarPrendas.java

```html
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        //
                Prenda ropa = new Prenda();
                ropa.setCodigo(Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("Codigo")));
                ropa.setNombre(request.getParameter("Nombre"));
                ropa.setMarca(request.getParameter("Marca"));         
                char t = request.getParameter("Talla").charAt(0);
                ropa.setTalla(t);
                //hora
                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                Date date = new Date();
                String fecha = dateFormat.format(date);
                ropa.setFechaIngreso(fecha);
                ropa.setStock(Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("Stock")));
                ropa.setTemporada(Boolean.valueOf(request.getParameter("Temporada")));
                //agregar a la lista
                Biblioteca.prenda.add(ropa);
                //                  
                for(Prenda cloth:Biblioteca.prenda){
                 request.setAttribute("codigo", cloth.getCodigo());
                 request.setAttribute("nombre", cloth.getNombre());
                 request.setAttribute("marca", cloth.getMarca());
                 request.setAttribute("talla", cloth.getTalla());
                 request.setAttribute("fecha", cloth.getFechaIngreso());
                 request.setAttribute("stock", cloth.getStock());
                 request.setAttribute("temporada", cloth.isTemporada());
                }           
                    RequestDispatcher despachador = request.getRequestDispatcher("ListadoDePrendas.jsp");
                despachador.forward(request, response);
    }
```

#### ListadoDePrendas.jsp

```html
 <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>JSP Page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Mis Prendas</h1>        
            <table border="1">
                <thead>
                <th>Codigo</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Marca</th>
                <th>Talla</th>
                <th>Fecha Ingreso</th>
                <th>Stock</th>
                <th>Temporada</th>    
                </thead>
                <tbody>               
                <tr>
                   <td><%= request.getAttribute("codigo") %></td>
                   <td><%= request.getAttribute("nombre") %></td>
                   <td><%= request.getAttribute("marca") %></td>
                   <td><%= request.getAttribute("talla") %></td>
                   <td><%= request.getAttribute("fecha") %></td>
                   <td><%= request.getAttribute("stock") %></td>
                   <td><%= request.getAttribute("temporada") %></td>
                   <td></td>
                </tr>                
                </tbody>           
            </table>
                <a href="index.jsp">Volver</a>  
        </body>   
    </html>
```

Comment: ¿En que sentido no hace nada? Por la consola del IDE o por la de desarrollador del navegador te debería pintar algún mensaje

Comment: cuando ingreso el formulario completo cambia a ListarPrenda y se queda en blanco y no pasa nada,cuando abro ListadoDePrendas.jsp a traves den link en el index,me sale la tabla con valores null

Comment: Bienvenido, aprovecho para invitarte a realizar el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y además revisa por favor [ask] para que en base a la información realices tus preguntas de acuerdo a el  [help] y sean bien recibida por la comunidad, Suerte!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te modifico un par de cosillas... y te pongo lo que no esta bien.

**Servlet:**

- Tienes en todas `request.getParameter("Codigo")`, `request.getParameter("Marca")` es decir, todos empiezan en mayúsculas, en cambio en tu formulario, en los `name` de cada `input` lo tienes en minúscula, por lo tanto nunca te van a llegar valores
- En el caso de los `select` el valor que te va a llegar es que tiene el atributo `value` del `option`, por lo tanto no te hace falta hacer el `.charAt(0)` para coger la primera letra, pues en el `value` tienes escrito lo que necesitas, con hacer el `request.getParameter("talla")` como en el resto de los `input`, te va a coger el valor que quieres.
- Entiendo que `Biblioteca` es una clase y que `prendas` es una variable `List` de tipo `static`  de la clase, como buena practica procura encapsular tu código, declara todas tus variables `private` y definiendo sus getter y sus setter, como bien has hecho en la clase `Prenda`. Tu `Servlet`, no va a morir tras hacer una redirección, las variables declaradas globalmente se van a mantener vivas ahí.
- En el `for` estas recorriendo todas tus prendas pero al hacer `request.setAttribute("codigo",codigo)`, estas reemplazando el valor con el elemento de cada vuelta, por lo tanto al final solo te quedaría el valor del ultimo elemento del bucle. en el `setAttribute` puedes meterle desde un `String` hasta el objeto que te de la gana (Como toda tu lista de prendas).

  ```
  Biblioteca biblioteca=new Biblioteca();

  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
              throws ServletException, IOException {
                 processRequest(request, response);
                 response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
          //
                  Prenda ropa = new Prenda();
                  ropa.setCodigo(Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("codigo")));
                  ropa.setNombre(request.getParameter("nombre"));
                  ropa.setMarca(request.getParameter("marca"));
                  ropa.setTalla(request.getParameter("talla"));
                  //hora
                  DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                  Date date = new Date();
                  String fecha = dateFormat.format(date);
                  ropa.setFechaIngreso(fecha);
                  ropa.setStock(Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("stock")));
                  ropa.setTemporada(Boolean.valueOf(request.getParameter("temporada")));
                  //agregar a la lista
                  biblioteca.getPrendas().add(ropa);
                  //                  
                  request.setAttribute("prendas", biblioteca.getPrendas());


                  RequestDispatcher despachador = request.getRequestDispatcher("ListadoDePrendas.jsp");
                  despachador.forward(request, response);
      }
  ```

**ListadoPrendas.jsp**

```
<%
 List<Prendas> lista=request.getAttribute("prendas");
 Iterator<Prendas> itPrendas=lista.iterator();
%>
<html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>JSP Page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Mis Prendas</h1>        
            <table border="1">
                <thead>
                <th>Codigo</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Marca</th>
                <th>Talla</th>
                <th>Fecha Ingreso</th>
                <th>Stock</th>
                <th>Temporada</th>    
                </thead>
                <tbody>
               <%while(itPrendas.hasNext()){
                  Prenda prenda=it.next();%>
                <tr>
                   <td><%= prenda.getCodigo() %></td>
                   <td><%= prenda.getNombre() %></td>
                   <td><%= prenda.getMarca() %></td>
                   <td><%= prenda.getTalla() %></td>
                   <td><%= prenda.getFecha() %></td>
                   <td><%= prenda.getStock() %></td>
                   <td><%= prenda.getTemporada() %></td>
                   <td></td>
                </tr>
               <%}%>                
                </tbody>           
            </table>
                <a href="index.jsp">Volver</a>  
        </body>   
    </html>
```

Versión con [JSTL](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm)

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
    <html>
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
                <title>JSP Page</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>Mis Prendas</h1>        
                <table border="1">
                    <thead>
                    <th>Codigo</th>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Marca</th>
                    <th>Talla</th>
                    <th>Fecha Ingreso</th>
                    <th>Stock</th>
                    <th>Temporada</th>    
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                   <c:forEach items="${prendas}" var="prenda">
                    <tr>
                       <td>${prenda.getCodigo()}</td>
                       <td>${prenda.getNombre()}</td>
                       <td>${prenda.getMarca()}</td>
                       <td>${prenda.getTalla()}</td>
                       <td>${prenda.getFecha()}</td>
                       <td>${prenda.getStock()}</td>
                       <td>${prenda.getTemporada()}</td>
                       <td></td>
                    </tr>
                   </c:forEach>                
                    </tbody>           
                </table>
                    <a href="index.jsp">Volver</a>  
            </body>   
        </html>
```

Comment: Recomendaría que ListadoPrendas.jsp sea codificado usando JSTL. A pesar que OP usa scriptlets, es mejor que aprenda de la manera correcta y evite el uso de scriptlets.

Comment: Lo he pensado, pero me parecía que antes de correr hay que aprender a andar ;) , ahora se la completo con JSTL

Comment: En mi opinión, enseñar a trabajar con scriptlets al año 2017 es como enseñar a caminar con un bastón =\ Está bueno enseñarlo como parte de la historia, así como se enseña en historia respecto a las cruzadas y de las guerras mundiales y que se aprende que ese tipo de cosas no deben repetirse

Comment: jajaja aunque estoy contigo, te sorprendería saber la de gente que sigue trabajando con scriplets. No digo que sea lo mas adecuado ni mucho menos, pero es así, de hecho JSTL también ya es casi un jubilado , gracias a frameworks como Spring y demas. En resumen, estoy contigo, pero el OP esta empezando con JSP, y yo lo he respondido con JSP :)

Comment: Por cierto @user59378, si te sirvio/gusto la respuesta, no dudes en marcarla como respuesta aceptada ;)

Comment: Esto da para un chat. Sí, sé que hay mucha gente que usa scriptlets así como usa Java 1.4 cuando estamos a puertas de Java 9 y el nuevo ciclo de releases. Y luego la gente pregunta por qué tanto odio hacia Java y que es lento y que es difícil de mantener y que bla bla bla... Pero dale, viene bien tener las dos alternativas base :)

Comment: jaja ya ves, de hecho, SO ya nos va diciendo que no vayamos al chat xD. Totalmente de acuerdo, aunque hay veces que es un proyecto tan antiguo, que habría básicamente que rehacerlo entero desde 0 para poder adaptarlo a los nuevos frameworks. Yo soy partidario, pero depende de cada empresa, y yo me conozco algunas muy gordas que aun tienen sus gestiones de inventario en programas de MSDOS... Pero si, lo suyo es ir procurando encauzar a los nuevos en caminos mas modernos si vemos que no lo hacen ellos.

Comment: Hola amigos,muchas gracias a todos por sus respuestas,sobretodo a @Hictus tu respuesta me ayudo mucho amigo,saludos.

Comment: Me alegra oírlo, para eso estamos socio ;)